# How to make vertical space independent of title content (with/without descenders)?

Tags: tikzposter

I have following tikzposter example with four blocks. In the top two blocks one of the titles is completely without descenders (`block x`) while the other one contains the letter `y` that goas below the text line (i.e. with descender). Now we see that The height of the two text blocks of the top two blocks is not aligned.

What is the "right" way to fix this?

You can "fix" it by adding a `\vphantom{y}` for this particular case (bottom two blocks), but that cannot possibly be the way that was intended for this!

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}
\title{Title}
\author{Authors}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{comment}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5}
\block{block x}{\blindtext}
\column{0.5}
\block{block y}{\blindtext}
\end{columns}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5}
\block{block x\vphantom{y}}{\blindtext}
\column{0.5}
\block{block y}{\blindtext}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Two possibilities, depending on whether you prefer the version with or without the descenders.  (Not tested.)  1) "With" descenders: add `\strut` at the end of the title (depends on correct font-size setting of `\strut` in class file).  2) No descenders: enclose the title in `\smash[b]{...}` (only works correctly on single-line titles).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the suggestions, these both look a little bit more generic than my `vphantom` solution. Still I wonder whether I'm doing something wrong with this `tikzposter` package itself, or whether it was an oversight of its authors.

Comment: TikZ nodes center the text relative to the top and bottom, not the baseline.  It is possible to correct this behavior using things like [anchor=base] or [baseline=(name.base)] but I doubt tikzposter gives you that much control.  Adding struts is easier.

Comment: `\vphantom` is functionally equivalent to a strut, and in fact may be more reliable than a strut.  When last I checked (years!), not all classes automatically rescaled the strut with a font size change.  I think you've got a good basic understanding of this particular situation.  +1  That said, I've observed that, in some fonts, the descender of the closing parenthesis may be longer than that of the "y", so be careful.